# Attach file with path based on cell value to email

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am trying to send an email with the below code from my workbook. It works fine but only until I try to attach a file.

The file is created by another VBA code and the file name is defined by the cell values specified below, but I get a debug error when I try to run the code and it won't attach. I've tested with a named path eg `C:test\test.docx` and it works fine.

How can I get it to accept the path based on the cell values? I've set it to `.Display` whilst testing rather than send.

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text 'ignore case sensitivity when comparing strings

Sub SendEmail()

Dim objOutlook As Object
Dim objMail As Object
Dim OL As Outlook.Application, ES As Worksheet, r As Long, i As Long
Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)
Dim path As String


path = "\\Wbcphfil01.wbc.lan\dts\Groups\Operational_Services\opserv_group\Enforcement\NRSWA\Licences\Mobile Plant\Applications 2019-20\" & Cells(i, 4) & " (" & Cells(i, 13) & ").docx"



    r = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 5 To r
        With Cells(i, 7)

            If .Value <> "" And Cells(i, 5) = "Mobile Plant" Then
                With objMail
                    .To = Cells(i, 11).Value
                    .Subject = "Your " & Cells(i, 5).Value & " licence - " & Cells(i, 4).Value
                    .Body = "abc"
                    .Attachments.Add path
                    .Display

End With
End If
End With

Next i

Set objOutlook = Nothing
Set objMail = Nothing


End Sub
```

Comment: Try `Debug.Print path` and see if the correct path is printed or not. Also you will benefit by correctly indenting your code.Makes it easier to spot errors and understand.

Comment: You are using `Cells(i, 4)` on the path to the file before you defined what the variable `i` actually is! Maybe move the path inside your For Loop?

Comment: I've found the error, I'd missed part of the file path rather stupidly.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Cells(i, 4) on the path to the file before you defined what the variable i actually is! Maybe move the path inside your For Loop?

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text 'ignore case sensitivity when comparing strings

Sub SendEmail()
Dim objOutlook As Object
Dim objMail As Object
Dim OL As Outlook.Application, ES As Worksheet, r As Long, i As Long
Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)
Dim path As String

r = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 5 To r
    path = "\\Wbcphfil01.wbc.lan\dts\Groups\Operational_Services\opserv_group\Enforcement\NRSWA\Licences\Mobile Plant\Applications 2019-20\" & Cells(i, 4) & " (" & Cells(i, 13) & ").docx"

    With Cells(i, 7)
        If .Value <> "" And Cells(i, 5) = "Mobile Plant" Then
            With objMail
                .To = Cells(i, 11).Value
                .Subject = "Your " & Cells(i, 5).Value & " licence - " & Cells(i, 4).Value
                .Body = "abc"
                .Attachments.Add path
                .Display
            End With
        End If
    End With
Next i

Set objOutlook = Nothing
Set objMail = Nothing
End Sub
```